# How can I move an edge loop along its normal?

Tags: modeling

I scaled the loop and it only moved along the XY plane.
[image: The loop only moved along the plane.]

Actually, I hope to get the result like below in the Maya.
[image: The loop moved along its normal.]

So, I wondering if there is any way to move the edge loops along their normal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what are you doing exactly in the second screenshot? it looks like you scale 2 edge loops?

Comment: Alt-S (Shrink/Fatten) will move vertices along their normals.